# remotebuild fails to deploy cordova application on iphone 6 device - iphone 5 device works fine

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using the new Cordova tools with Visual Studio 2015. The mac build server is running the remotebuild agent. I can use the simulator or deploy to an iPhone 5 device successfully.

When I attempt to deploy to an iPhone 6 Plus device, remotebuild agent crashes with this stack trace:

```
GET /cordova/build/17124/deploy 404 5053.994 ms - 52
****** Server will shutdown due to uncaught error ****** 
[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:154:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:240:15)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/elliot/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/1.0.0/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/ios/ios.js:172:33)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
****** Performing server shutdown procedures.
```

I am certain the provisioning profiles are set correctly.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a workaround?

Comment: I'm getting this same error. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your VS output you will see a message along the lines of “application verification failed”, complaining about their provisioning profile. Are you sure that you have the correct provisioning profile installed on your iPhone 6 plus?

Thanks for reporting the crash on the server side. There might be issue on our side where we might accidentally try to respond twice to the same request, which is an error and produces the crash of the server.